# wxPython how to play once or disable loop in GIFAnimationCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, animated-gif

I have an animated GIF played by `GIFAnimationCtrl()` on my **Python** code. Since my GIF is triggered by user events I need to just play it once.

I tried just exporting the GIF without the looping attribute and trying if the function `Play()` has any options, but it doesn't. Any other function or libary I could use with **wxPython** is also wellcomed.

Here is the image i'm trying to use.

[image: drag_event]

Answer (score 0):

After more research i just found a workaround, wich is to put on the last frame of the animated GIF, a 240 seconds delay (the maximum I can put on Photoshop) wich does the trick,

Still looking for better aproaches.